# Regular Expression Works With Everything But Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am trying to use python to go through a list of files and pull out blocks of configurations. The file is formatted as follows:

```
pon-onu-mng gpon-onu_1/2/2:8
  ip-host 2 dhcp-enable true ping-response true traceroute-response true
  dhcp-ip ethuni eth_0/1 from-internet
  dhcp-ip ethuni eth_0/2 from-internet
  wifi disable
#
pon-onu-mng gpon-onu_1/2/2:9
  ip-host 2 dhcp-enable true ping-response true traceroute-response true
  dhcp-ip ethuni eth_0/1 from-internet
  dhcp-ip ethuni eth_0/2 from-internet
  wifi disable
#
pon-onu-mng gpon-onu_1/2/2:10
  ip-host 2 dhcp-enable true ping-response true traceroute-response true
  dhcp-ip ethuni eth_0/1 from-internet
  dhcp-ip ethuni eth_0/2 from-internet
  wifi disable
#
```

There are other lines before and after these, but all of the ones I need begin with 'pon-onu-mng gpon-onu' and go until the # symbol. I need to capture this entire block with both "terminators" included.

Am using this regular expression to find the blocks:pon-onu-mng.gpon-onu(.*?|[\S\s]?)#
I am able to plug this into python's re without getting any errors (this caused me issues) but it returns an empty list. I tested the expression on regex101.com and it finds everything I need. The code I have so far is below. Could anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import os
from optparse import OptionParser
import re
import pandas as pd

configFileListRaw = os.system('find . -name startrun.dat > configFileList.txt')
configFileListRaw = open('configFileList.txt').readlines()
os.system('rm configFileList.txt')

pattern = re.compile(r'pon-onu-mng.gpon-onu(.*?|[\S\s]?)#')
#match = re.findall(pattern,"pon-onu-mng gpon-onu")
print(pattern)

for i in configFileListRaw:
    file = open (str(i).strip("\n"))
    match = re.findall(r'pon-onu-mng.gpon-onu(.*?|[\S\s]?)#',file.read(),re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    print (match)
```

From Regex101: (there was suppsoed to be an image here but I think it just attached it)

Output from running the script. Note - the re.compile (second line) is just a print statement I put in to make sure re.compile was compiling what I expected. As you can see, I am no longer using re.compile, I put the regex directly into the re.findall function:

```
tymier@FL-ENG026-LT:/mnt/scriptdev/gitlab/zte-phone-parser/2023-04-05-02-00-16/10.57.4.227$ ../../zte_phone_parser.py
re.compile('pon-onu-mng.gpon-onu(.*?|[\\S\\s]?)#')
[]
```

I've tried googling until the cows come home. I was able to figure out that I need either MULTILINE or DOTALL, and probably both, but not sure honestly.

Comment: Why do you need `[\S\s]*` when you're using `re.DOTALL`?

Comment: `i` is already a string, you don't need to use `str(i)`.

Comment: You don't need `re.MULTILINE` if the regexp doesn't contain `^` or `$`.

Comment: It seems to work here: https://ideone.com/ioal4g

Comment: @Barmar the answer to all of your questions is "Because I was trying everything". This was just the latest iteration of what I was doing.

Comment: "trying everything" is the hallmark of "cargo cult programming". Read the documentation of the options to see whether they're actually related to the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue had to do with how I was reading the file in. I started over and focused on reading the file and searching it. I was finally able to get the following to work:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import re

file = open('startrun.dat','r').read()
match = re.findall(r'pon-onu-mng.gpon-onu(.*?|[\S\s]?)!',file,re.DOTALL)

for i in match:
    print (i)
```